# Does Xiao jump-climb higher than other characters of the same body type?

Tags: genshin-impact

My kid got Xiao in the new banner and I watched him (with Xiao) climb a cliff I know well, going apparently faster than I am used to. To me, it seems Xiao clears more height when he jumps while climbing.

I searched the web but got no conclusive results. Too much cluttter for my google-fu.

Therefore, *Does Xiao jump-climb higher than other characters of the same body type?*

Answer (score 2):

No, Xiao does not climb higher than other characters of the same body type. The only thing he offers is a reduction in stamina consumed while climbing, thus allowing him to use more powered jumps, making it seem like he is faster than you.